# Does anyone know of an Illustrated/Animated Audio Bible resource on YouTube or other video platforms?

Tags: sources-mekorot, internet, social-media

I'm looking for a YouTube playlist or something along those lines which includes an Audio Bible reading along with illustrated images as the audio keeps going.

The focus is on the five books of Moses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Aleph Beta](https://www.alephbeta.org/welcome).

They have weekly animated films for every parsha which you can see [here](https://www.alephbeta.org/weekly-torah-portion/parshat-nitzavim-vayeilech).